# How to get latest records of a model according to create date of record using search() method of ORM API in Odoo 9?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want to access data of two latest records of a model using ORM API's `record.search()` method in Odoo 9. Is it possible to get the data of two latest records based on the value of create date field in a model? This is the code I am going to get the latest records with it:

```
@api.multi
def get_data(self, rec):
    reference_data = self.env['recuite.reference.reference'].search([('recruite_id', '=', rec.id)])
```

What parameter should I add to search method to get intended result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add two arguments to the search method:

```
, order='create_date desc', limit=2)
```

Parameters

- **args** -- A search domain. Use an empty
  list to match all records.
- **offset** (`int`) -- number of results to ignore (default: none)
- **limit** (`int`) -- maximum number of records to return (default: all)
- **order** (`str`) -- sort string
- **count** (`bool`) -- if True, only counts and returns the number of matching records (default: False)

**Returns:** at most `limit` records matching the search criteria
**Raises: AccessError** --

- if user tries to bypass access rules for read on the requested object.